# Apply modifier keys to characters

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

What's the best way to apply the modifier keys of the keyboard to a character to get it's modified value (for the current culture)?

For example, with shift pressed (for a UK keyboard):

```
Assert.AreEqual('!', Modify('1'));
Assert.AreEqual('"', Modify('2'));
Assert.AreEqual('A', Modify('a'));
Assert.AreEqual('B', Modify('b'));
Assert.AreEqual(':', Modify(';'));
Assert.AreEqual('?', Modify('/'));
```

I have a way to tell if the modifier keys are pressed, what I don't have is a way to then map to the correct character given this set of modifier keys.

Comment: I'd say a dictionary but that's not very scalable, particularly if you have to support multiple keyboard layouts.

Comment: @JeffMercado and it will be even worse if the user uses a modified custom keyboard layout!

Comment: @JeffMercado I considered that but this is for an application likely to be used in many regions, so it's just not feasible to solve the problem myself.

Comment: This is not something you can get from an encoding or culture. Those relations are (only) defined in the keyboard driver software.

Comment: This is not possible at all. Modify('1') must and should return a list of results (for example on English layout it is "!" and "End"). And is highly dependent on the keyboard locale.

Comment: Then again you have such weird modifications like in croatian you can type german letters: "AltGr + 'key before 1' followed by 'u'" is a modifier of ü, where the key before 1 is a dead key which works only as a modifer for the followign keypress.

Comment: @Marino, I actually have the keys that have been pressed (where 1 and Numpad1 are different keys). So, as you rightly say although modifying chars is impossible I can directly modify the keys enum instead if necessary.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, the following might do:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);

    [Test]
    public void Test_VkKeyScan()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(VkKey('!'), VkKey('1'));
        Assert.AreEqual(VkKey('@'), VkKey('2'));
    }

    private short VkKey(char p)
    {
        return (short)(0xff & VkKeyScan(p));
    }
```

Building a dictionary using the provided `VkKey` method should not be too much of an issue either.

UPDATE: Handling multiple layouts properly would require using `VkKeyScanEx` instead of `VkKeyScan` and providing the current or needed layout explicitly as a parameter.